# Avoiding to repeat the same code block twice in MVC razor view

Tags: c#, razor

This is probably very simple, but I just haven´t found the way yet.... :)

I have this code in a cshtml view (example is simplified):

```
@if(Model.LinkUrl != null)
{
    <a href="@Model.LinkUrl">
        <h2>@Model.Name</h2>
        <img src="@Model.ImageUrl" />
    </a>
} else {
    <div>
        <h2>@Model.Name</h2>
        <img src="@Model.ImageUrl" />
    </div>
}
```

Depending if the Model has a link in it or not I must wrap the same code ( and ) in an  or a .

Is there a way to avoid repeating this code:

```
<h2>@Model.Name</h2>
<img src="@Model.ImageUrl" />
```

I.e. having some kind of helper method/mixin that I can call to render it?

Comment: What about a partial view? You just pass the Model as a parameter to the partial view and render it everytime you want to use the same piece of code.

Comment: I am already in a partial view and in Umbraco CMS (in which I work) I can´t add a partial view inside a partial view.

But if it is possible in C# in general then it is probably also in Umbraco and I can find answer in an Umbraco forum. Is it possible in C# in general?

Comment: You can render partial views inside another partial view with `@Html.Partial("PartialViewName", Model)`

Comment: Thanks - I will look into how I do it wrong in my setup, then. :)